# "Could not find declaration file for module," but it exists

Tags: typescript

I've created a very simple custom declaration for `react-native-simple-radio-button` that I've placed under `src/@types/react-native-simple-radio-button/index.d.ts`

```
import { Component } from 'react';

declare module 'react-native-simple-radio-button' {
  export default class RadioForm extends Component {}
}
```

In my code, I have `import RadioForm from 'react-native-simple-radio-button`. The module is installed in `node_modules`, but when I try to run the code with TypeScript I get:

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-simple-radio-button'. 'project/node_modules/react-native-simple-radio-button/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native-simple-radio-button` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-simple-radio-button';`
```

However, I *do* have the `index.d.ts` file that I've declared. I've created other declaration modules in `src/@types` and those are working okay.

Is there anything else I need to do to get TypeScript to recognize my declaration for this module?

Comment: Have you tried defining it as `src/@types/react-native-simple-radio-button.d.ts`? Also, what does your tsconfig look like? Is the `@types/` directory properly included?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create folder in your /src folder.

> @types

Step 2: Create file inside it called:

> react-native-simple-radio-button.d.ts

Step 3: Add `declare module 'react-native-simple-radio-button;`

Error should now be gone. At least that worked for me. Coment from nguida and solution from ford04 did the trick, I just wrote it here step by step.

Comment: Although this user is a new contributor ...
but this answer seems to be very objective, which can result in the solution.

Be sure to send your feedback

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains about the non-existent module type `react-native-simple-radio-button`, because you create an [ambient module *augmentation*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) instead of an [ambient module *declaration*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#122-ambient-module-declarations).

You need to define the latter, when no type of the module exists at all in the global namespace. That's the case for your button library, as the package itself does not contain types  and also does not provide a `@types` package. So how does an ambient declaration look like?

> An AmbientModuleDeclaration declares a module. This type of declaration is permitted only at the top level in a source file that contributes to the global namespace. [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#122-ambient-module-declarations)

So remove all `import`/`export` statements in `index.d.ts` so that `react-native-simple-radio-button` module type declaration is removed from module scope and added in global scope. Or put it in its own .d.ts file without `import`/`export`.